# Changing css in richfaces

Tags: css, richfaces

I'm trying to change the font and some other css class in richfaces.

My question is how can I access the skin parameters like #{richSkin.generalFamilyFont}?
or is there another way to change the font?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Skins in RichFaces can be customized on each of the three levels:

- Skin property files

Application interfaces can be modified by altering the values of skin parameters in the skin itself. Edit the constant values defined in the skin.properties file to change the style of every component mapped to that skin property.

- Component stylesheets

Mappings and other style attributes listed in a component's ECSS file can be edited. Edit the ECSS file to change the styles of all components of that type.

- Custom components style classes

Individual components can use the styleClass attribute to use a unique style class. Add the new style class to the application CSS and reference it from an individual component with the styleClass attribute.

- Overwriting stylesheets in application

You can load custom stylesheets using  which rewrites of extends styles defined for style classes of components.

More details you can find [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html)

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Where can I find the file skin.properties?